# How does darkmail (DIME) work to hide email metadata?

Tags: encryption

While Email encryption can protect the content of an email, the metadata are still readable and can be used to gather important information about the sender and the receiver.

There were several news articles about the Darkmail project, which aims to increase privacy in email communication. The initiative is developing a new mail protocol which shall also protect metadata. However, the news articles generally avoided going into the technical details about how this is to be achieved. The official site https://www.darkmail.info, on the other hand, provides mostly very technical information and specifications of the protocol.

Can anyone please explain in layman terms how Darkmail works?